# New MDI child resizes other maximized Forms

Tags: forms, vb6, mdichild

I have a project with a main MDI form.  There is a child MDI form inside that is always present and cannot be closed (Is it possible to hide the close button while keeping the min and max buttons?).  Because the child form is such an important part of the program, users like to have it maximized.  When another MDI child pops up, the maximized form returns to its original size.

Is there a way to keep an MDIchild maximized with other forms floating around in front?  Or can only the active form be maximized at any particular time?

EDIT - I'm specifically looking for whether or not VB6 supports such an operation.  Although work-arounds may be helpful, I'd prefer a simple yes or no answer.  So far it seems like 'no'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back, I'm pretty sure that what you're describing is the normal way this things should be handled.  What I'd do is open that important form up so that it fills the whole MDI child area, but doesn't put its minimize-maximize buttons in the toolbar. Lock and anchor it there then handle the closequery method to not allow it to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If the child MDI form in question is "always present" and users like to keep it maximized, then it really shouldn't be a child form.  Instead, move the GUI features from this form to the main form.  You can put these controls on a panel (or other docking control) so that users can hide it and show it as required.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution. However, I am not responsible for the design of the project and I think the transfer of the controls would be too large of a task for such a simple issue.  If there's simply no way to keep the form maximized in the presence of other forms, then that would be the answer to my question.